# How to find IP Address to username?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, radius

I have a Desktop application developed in `C#`, that can find the all the users in an `Active Directory` network and their corresponding `IP Address`.

To Find the `Users`, it contacts the `Global Catalog Server` and to get the `IP Address` it reads the Security events from respective `Domain Controllers`.

Now, I want to do the same for all the other `Directory Services`.

Can some one suggest if there would be a generic way to get the `IP Address` of all the users who gets authenticated against any `Directory Services`?

One of the suggestion from my friend is to use or host a `Radius` server and make other other `Directory Services` send account messages to that server and my program reads those information from the radius server.

I am not sure, if that's even possible. I know NAS devices will send accounting messages to `Radius` server, but will `Directory Servers` do that?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of tool is this? Desktop or Web?

If it's Web you could use the `REMOTE_ADDR` header of the HttpRequest

Comment: I think you have not read the question correcty..OP is not asking to find IP address of User using Tool....OP is asking to read IP address of all User in that Domain controller.....Even if this is Web tool, asnwer you suggested will not solve OP problem

Comment: Perhaps i did not understand the question.